# SQL table queue - run procedure on data receipt

Tags: sql-server, triggers, queue, message-queue, service-broker

I'm optimizing a legacy application and only have access to the database, not the UI code.

There is a specific table insert occurring that I need to catch, so I can do some additional processing, but without adding any obvious lag.

I'm thinking of adding an INSERT trigger which places an entry on a queue, so that processing can continue after returning.

SQL queues using the Service Broker seem to require a 2-way conversation, therefore 2 queues. I don't need this so another possibility could be to use a table as a queue.

But, if I use a table, is there a way for entries to be processed very soon after they arrive, as would be the case with a Service Broker SQL queue? Is the only option to have checks running at a scheduled period? This would be a pain if I need to add more.
A trigger on that "Queue" table would also not be a great idea as it would add to performance lag.

Of course I could always just ignore the response queue, but that doesn't feel right.

Comment: How soon is "very soon"? You can have a job that looks for new rows in the queue as frequently as every second. Though usually for the sanity of history tables in msdb it's much better to run every minute or more and within the job have multiple checks against the queue separated by more granular waitfors.

Comment: I'd rather not have a scheduled task type job running at all, but would prefer a process was "kicked-off" by the arrival of the data, if possible.

Comment: Ok, then service broker is the way to do that. I thought you were interested in using a table as a queue. That would have to get processed separately unless you wanted to make the caller do it. Scheduled tasks are how we generally accomplish tasks asynchronously, so it's probably a good idea to embrace them rather than shun them. Anything that is "automatic but after" is responding to an event - doesn't really matter what that event source is.

Comment: That's exactly what I want, but without the unnecessary second queue if possible.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure where you heard you need a second queue (or why it's a problem if you only have to set it up once and then forget about it), but [read this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/66141/1186) (and the comments and links). Most people do end up recognizing that a queue table is more flexible and less complex than service broker, even if they do have to use an icky SQL Server Agent job.